# Intermediate value theorem on infinite interval

Tags: calculus

Let $g\geq 0$ on $[a,\infty)$, and $\int_a^\infty g(x)\,dx<\infty$. Also, $f$ is continuous, bounded on $[a,\infty)$. Show that there exists a $\xi \in [a,\infty)$ such that $$\int_a^\infty f(x)g(x)\,dx=f(\xi)\int_a^\infty g(x)\,dx.$$

This is extension of Intermediate value theorem.

Comment: Perhaps you mean an extension of the mean value theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M= \sup_{x \ge a} f(x), m = \inf_{x \ge a} f(x)$ and
$G = \int_{x \ge a} g(x) dx$. Since $g(x) \ge 0$ we have
$m g(x) \le f(x)g(x) \le M g(x)$ and so
$m G \le I=\int_{x \ge a} f(x)g(x) dx \le MG$.

If $G=0$, then $g(x) = 0$ ae. and hence $I=0$ and so any $x\ge a$ will do, so suppose $G>0$.

If $m G =I$, then we must have $f(x) = m$ ae., so we can choose any $x$ such that $f(x) = m$. Similarly for the upper bound.

Hence we may assume that $m < {I \over G} < M$. By definition of $\inf,\sup$ there exist $x_m,x_M$ such that $m \le f(x_m) < {I \over G} < f(x_M) \le  M$ and then by the usual intermediate value theorem we can find some $x \in [x_m,x_M]$ such that $f(x) = {I \over G}$ which is the desired result.